# sometimes ubuntu wont boot to GUI

Tags: boot, login

Every time when reboot/boot ubuntu, it does load grub successfully,but after grub most of the time it shows cursor blinking in top left corner and wont move to login screen.

I had to reboot several times,until login screen appear.

Comment: Could you update your question to include some system logs from when a boot fails? This might make it possible to offer some assistance, otherwise everything will be a complete guess.

Comment: i think, it happen cause of nvidia driver

Answer (score 0):

solved after, i changed nvidia prime profile to "On demand" option from "performance mode".
[image]

Comment: You may find that this doesn't completely resolve the issue: I experience the same issue *sometimes*, and I already have the "On-Demand" option selected. I find that pressing <CTRL><ALT><F1>,<CTRL><ALT><F2>,<CTRL><ALT><F3>, and finally <CTRL><ALT><F1> again fixes this. The <CTRL><ALT><F#> sequence switches to a different "tty", and for some reason, switching away from the first tty and back to it seems to remedy the issue. I haven't bothered to try to figure out what the root-cause is, since this is a minor inconvenience, and the "trick" I just explained quickly works-around the problem.